# Analytics Embd API - how to cut out View Selector from Custom Component Demo

Tags: javascript, charts, google-analytics-api

So I need only one ids and not View Selector, but whenever I try to just cut it out my charts don't render on page.

Here's code:

```js
      
        gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        /**
         * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
         */
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
          'serverAuth': {
            'access_token': '<?php print_r($myToken["access_token"]); ?>'
          }
        });






 /**
   * Store a set of common DataChart config options since they're shared by
   * both of the charts we're about to make.
   */
 


  /**
   * Query params representing the first chart's date range.
   */
  var dateRange1 = {
    'start-date': '14daysAgo',
    'end-date': '8daysAgo'
  };



  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
    container: 'view-selector-container',
  }).execute();


  /**
   * Create a new DateRangeSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "date-range-selector-1-container", set its date range
   * and then render it to the page.
   */
  var dateRangeSelector1 = new gapi.analytics.ext.DateRangeSelector({
    container: 'date-range-selector-1-container'
  })
  .set(dateRange1)
  .execute();











  /**
   * Register a handler to run whenever the user changes the view.
   * The handler will update both dataCharts as well as updating the title
   * of the dashboard.
   */
  viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
 
    
      setTimeout(function(){
      sesjewykreswom.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
       sesjemwykresliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
        uzytkownicymwykresliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
         odslonymwykresliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
          womwykresliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
           nowesesjeprocmwykresliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
            nowipowracajacywykreskliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
                  }, 500);
                
            setTimeout(function(){    
             ruchmobilny.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
             najlepszekanalywykresk.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
             seostronydocelowetabela.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
             celeogolemwykres.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
             celewspolczynnikkonwersjiliczba.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
              }, 2500);
              
                setTimeout(function(){
            mapamiastapolski.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
            
           
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    alert('wczytano dane');
                    document.getElementById('pleasWaitX2').style.display = "none"; 
                    }, 3000
                ); 
            
        }, 4500);
   
        alert('wykonuje sie to 00000000000000');

    var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
    title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';
  });


  /**
   * Register a handler to run whenever the user changes the date range from
   * the first datepicker. The handler will update the first dataChart
   * instance as well as change the dashboard subtitle to reflect the range.
   */
  dateRangeSelector1.on('change', function(data) {
  
    
            setTimeout(function(){
      sesjewykreswom.set({query: data}).execute();
       sesjemwykresliczba.set({query: data}).execute();
        uzytkownicymwykresliczba.set({query: data}).execute();
         odslonymwykresliczba.set({query: data}).execute();
          womwykresliczba.set({query: data}).execute();
           nowesesjeprocmwykresliczba.set({query:data}).execute();
            nowipowracajacywykreskliczba.set({query: data}).execute();
                  }, 500);
                
            setTimeout(function(){    
             ruchmobilny.set({query: data}).execute();
             najlepszekanalywykresk.set({query: data}).execute();
             seostronydocelowetabela.set({query:data}).execute();
             celeogolemwykres.set({query: data}).execute();
             celewspolczynnikkonwersjiliczba.set({query:data}).execute();
              }, 2500);
              
                setTimeout(function(){
            mapamiastapolski.set({query: data}).execute();
            
           
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    alert('wczytano dane');
                    document.getElementById('pleasWaitX2').style.display = "none"; 
                    }, 3000
                ); 
            
        }, 4500);
    
    
    alert('wykonuje sie to 111111');
    // Update the "from" dates text.
    var datefield = document.getElementById('from-dates');
    datefield.innerHTML = data['start-date'] + '&mdash;' + data['end-date'];
  });




































        var sesjewykreswom = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
              'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
             // 'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
             // 'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
              'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:organicSearches',
              'dimensions': 'ga:deviceCategory'
            },
            chart: {
              'container': 'sesje-wykres-wom',
              'type': 'COLUMN',
              'options': {
                'width': '100%',
                'title': 'Porównanie ruchu organicznego z ruchem ogólnym'
              }
            }
        });
        
        var sesjemwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
           // 'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO

            'metrics':'ga:sessions'
          },
           chart: {
            'container': 'sesje-mwykres-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {

            }
          }

        });
          
        var uzytkownicymwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO

            'metrics':'ga:users'
          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'uzytkownicy-mwykres-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {

            }
          }
        });
       
        var odslonymwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
        //    'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO

            'metrics':'ga:pageviews'
          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'odslony-mwykres-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {

            }
          }
        });
       
        var womwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:bounceRate'

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'wo-mwykres-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {
              'title': 'Współczynnik odrzuceń'
            }
          }
        });
        
        var nowesesjeprocmwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:percentNewSessions'

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'nowe-sesje-proc-mwykres-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {
              'title': 'Współczynnik odrzuceń'
            }
          }
        });
        
        var nowipowracajacywykreskliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
            'dimensions': 'ga:userType'

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'nowi-powracajacy-wykresk-liczba',
            'type': 'PIE',
            'options': {
           'sliceVisibilityThreshold': '.01',
               pieHole: 4/9
            }
          }
        });
        
        var mapamiastapolski = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
          //  'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'dimensions': 'ga:city',
                     'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'mapa-miasta-polski',
            'type': 'GEO',
            'options': {
              'title': 'mapka',
              'displayMode': 'markers',
              'region':'PL'
            }
          }
        });
       
        var ruchmobilny = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
          //  'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
          //  'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions',
             'dimensions':'ga:channelGrouping',

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'ruch-mobilny',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {
              'title': 'Współczynnik odrzuceń'
            }
          }
        });
       
        var najlepszekanalywykresk = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
           // 'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
          //  'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
            'dimensions': 'ga:channelGrouping'

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'najlepsze-kanaly-wykresk',
            'type': 'PIE',
            'options': {
           'sliceVisibilityThreshold': '.01',
               pieHole: 4/9
            }
          }
        });
        
        var seostronydocelowetabela = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
           // 'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
          //  'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'dimensions': 'ga:landingPagePath',
                     'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'seo-stronydocelowe-tabela',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {
              'title': 'Strony Docelowe'
            }
          }
        });
        
        var celeogolemwykres = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
          //  'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:goalCompletionsAll',
           'dimensions': 'ga:date'
          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'cele-ogolem-wykres',
            'type': 'LINE',
            'options': {
              'width': '100%',

            }
          }
        });
        
        var celewspolczynnikkonwersjiliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
         //   'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
         //   'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
            'metrics': 'ga:goalConversionRateAll'

          },
          chart: {
            'container': 'cele-wspolczynnik-konwersji-liczba',
            'type': 'TABLE',
            'options': {
              'title': 'Współczynnik odrzuceń'
            }
          }
        });
```

Any help will be welcome.

And other trouble I have: I would like to make buttons to change start time and end time monthly like: december, january etc.. I don't know how though and help will be welcome.